# Exception handling using an HttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, httpmodule

We're reviewing one of the company's system's exception handling and found a couple of interesting things.

Most of the code blocks (if not all of them) are inside a try/catch block, and inside the catch block a new BaseApplicationException is being thrown - which seems to be coming from the Enterprise Libraries. 
I'm in a bit of a trouble here as I don't see the benefits off doing this. (throwing another exception anytime one occurs)
One of the developers who's been using the system for a while said it's because that class's in charge of publishing the exception (sending emails and stuff like that) but he wasn't too sure about it. 
After spending some time going through the code I'm quite confident to say, that's all it does is collecting information about the environment and than publishing it.

My question is:
 - Is it reasonable to wrap all the code inside try { } catch { } blocks and than throw a new exception? And if it is, why? What's the benefit?

My personal opinion is that it would be much easier to use an HttpModule, sign up for the Error event of the Application event, and do what's necessary inside the module. If we'd go down this road, would we miss something? Any drawbacks?

Your opinion's much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Never**<sup>1</sup> `catch (Exception ex)`. Period<sup>2</sup>. There is no way you can handle all the different kinds of errors that you may catch.

Never<sup>3</sup> catch an Exception-derived type if you can't handle it or provide additional information (to be used by subsequent exception handlers). Displaying an error message is **not** the same as *handling* the error.

A couple of reasons for this, from the top of my head:

- Catching and rethrowing is expensive
- You'll end up losing the stack trace
- You'll have a low signal-to-noice ratio in your code

If you know how to handle a **specific** exception (and reset the application to pre-error state), catch it. (That's why it's called *exception* ***handling***.)

To handle exceptions that are not caught, listen for the appropriate events. When doing WinForms, you'll need to listen for `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`, and - if your doing `Threading` - `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException.` For web apps, there are similar mechanisms (`System.Web.HttpApplication.Error`).

As for wrapping framework exceptions in your application (non-)specific exceptions (i.e. `throw new MyBaseException(ex);`): Utterly pointless, and a bad smell.<sup>4</sup>

---

***Edit***

<sup>1</sup> *Never* is a very harsh word, especially when it comes to engineering, as @Chris pointed out in the comments. I'll admit to being high on principles when I first wrote this answer.

<sup>2,3</sup> See <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>4</sup> If you don't bring anything new to the table, I still stand by this. If you have caught `Exception ex` as part of a method that you know could fail in any number of ways, I believe that the current method should reflect that in it's signature. And as you know, exceptions is not part of the method signature.

Comment: -1 for use of NEVER. The words never and always in engineering are *almost* always wrong. There are many valid cases for `catch(Exception ex)` mostly related to working with external resources be they disk, server, or web url. When an external dependency is faulted all kinds of crazy exceptions can be generated to try to handle each specifically is futile normally you would just uniformly handle any failed access to a resource, or uniformly fail. This also gets into when wrapping exceptions such as `throw new DatabaseOfflineException(innerException)` become perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Chris: I actually agree with you, regarding the engineering aspect of programming. I'll update the answer. (This answer is my very first on SO, and the fact that the question/answer gets attention 2+ years later is just awesome. SO's awesome!)

Comment: @Chris: The objection that "You'll end up losing the stack trace" would only be true if you don't include the exception in your re-thrown exception. Most exception constructors will take an exception to include as its inner exception. Still, I agree that, in most cases, simply catching and re-throwing exceptions is a waste of time (unless, of course, extra and truly useful information is packaged in the re-thrown exception).

Answer (score 2):

If I am reading the question correctly, I would say that implementing a try / catch which intercept exceptions (you don't mention - is it catching all exceptions, or just a specific one?) and throws a different exception is generally a bad thing.

### Disadvantages:

At the very least you will lose stack trace information - the stack you will see will only extend to the method in which the new exception is thrown - you potentially lose some good debug info here.

If you are catching Exception, you are running the risk of masking critical exceptions, like OutOfMemory or StackOverflow with a less critical exception, and thus leaving the process running, where perhaps it should have been torn down.

### Possible Advantages:

In some very specific cases you could take an exception which doesn't have much debug value (like some exceptions coming back from a database) and wrap with an exception which adds more context, e.g id of the object you were dealing with.

However, in almost all cases this is a bad smell and should be used with caution.

Generally you should only catch an exception when there is something realistic that you can do in that location- ie recovering, rolling back, going to plan B etc. If there is nothing you can do about it, just allow it to pass up the chain. You should only catch and throw a new exception if there is specific and useful data available in that location which can augment the original exception and hence aid debugging.

Comment: It catches all kind of exceptions and it's all around the code..
In every method, the logic looks like:
            try { //code }
            catch (Exception ex){
                throw new BaseApplicationException(ex, this);
            }

Answer (score 1):

I'm from the school of thought where try/ catch blocks should be used and exceptions not rethrown. If you have executing code which is likely to error then it should be handled, logged and something returned. Rethrowing the exception only serves the purpose to re-log later in the application life cycle.

Here's an interesting post on how to use a HttpModule to handle exceptions: http://blogs.msdn.com/rahulso/archive/2008/07/13/how-to-use-httpmodules-to-troubleshoot-your-asp-net-application.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/rahulso/archive/2008/07/18/asp-net-how-to-write-error-messages-into-a-text-file-using-a-simple-httpmodule.aspx

Comment: If you do not fully understand the exception and how to recover from it, you should never swallow it.  And you should never swallow an exception within a class library.  Only code high up on the call stack truly understands what is going on and how to handle exceptions, IMHO.

Comment: If you have an exception which you don't know how to recover from is it really an "expected" exception? I'd class something I can't recover from as an unexpected exception and that I would not catch.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).  It does what you're talking about.  Very well.

When I create libraries I try to always provide a reduced number of exceptions for callers to handle.  For example, think of a Repository component that connects to a sql database.  There are TONS of exceptions, from sql client exceptions to invalid cast exceptions, that can theoretically be thrown.  Many of these are clearly documented and can be accounted for at compile time.  So, I catch as many of them as I can, place them in a single exception type, say a RepositoryException, and let that exception roll up the call stack.

The original exception is retained, so the original exception can be diagnosed.  But my callers only need to worry about handling a single exception type rather than litter their code with tons of different catch blocks.

There are, of course, some issues with this.  Most notably, if the caller can handle some of these exceptions, they have to root around in the RepositoryException and then switch on the type of the inner exception to handle it.  Its less clean than having a single catch block for a single exception type.  I don't think thats much of an issue, however.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the exception that is thrown should not have been implemented as an exception.

Anyway, I would say that since this BaseApplicationException is a general all-purpose exception, it would be good to throw exceptions that are more context-specific. So when you are trying to retrieve an entity from a database, you might want an EntityNotFoundException. This way when you are debugging you do not have to search through inner exceptions and stack traces to find the real issue. If this BAseApplicationException is collecting information on the exception (like keeping track of the inner exception) then this should not be a problem.

I would use the HttpModule only when I could not get any closer to where the exceptions are actually happening in code. You do not really want an HttModule OnError event that is a giant switch statement depending on BaseApplicationexception's error information.

To conclude, it is worth it to throw different exceptions when you can give more specific exceptions that tell you the root of the problem right off the bat.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, catch the exception, add the error to the Server (?) object. This will allow .NET to do what ever it needs to do, then display your exception.