# Are there any guidance resources available in regards to error handling INSIDE of HttpModules?

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, httpmodule

I attempted to find any information in regards to best practices of handling errors inside of a HttpModule unfortunately I can't seem to find any information on Google in regards to this.

All the information I've found all pertains in how to use the global.asax or a custom http module to log errors which is completely not pertinent.

**Edit:** Clearly this question has been misunderstood. I am seeking information regarding software patterns that are employed to prevent a HttpModules from faulting, triggering custom errors redirection, and faulting again causing infinite exception chains until IIS shuts down the thread entirely.

This however is very nontrivial since the HttpSessionState collection can't be depended on for the life cycle of HttpModules. Since error conditions have already occurred it would be improper to expect that I could read the ASP.NET session cookie to get an identifier that I could store user specific data in the application cache. Storing data in the HttpRequest.Items collection would be pointless since that in no way exists across multiple requests.

My final conclusion was that I had to use cookies to store this intermediary information.

Comment: I would assume standard application error handling applies in this case as well

Answer (score -1):

As K Ivanov said, standard error handling practices apply the same here as anywhere else.

Wrap your code in try .. catch statements.  Then handle them appropriately and/or log them for further review.  Logging can take forms such as storing the info into a database, writing to a text file, etc.

There is nothing really special about HttpModules.

Comment: Except if IIS deems your module has faulted it completely abandons serving a request

Comment: @Chris Marisic: I'm not sure what that has to do with capturing the error and logging it.  If the module just lets the error bubble up then sure IIS is going to kill the request.  However, you should be catching these.

Comment: This has nothing to do with logging, I was stating I could find no information in regards to this except about how to use http modules to log errors which is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Chris Marisic: There is some disconnect between us.  My understanding is that you asked how to handle errors in an HttpModule.  My answer is to just do it the same way as you would in any other piece of code, there's nothing special here.  If I've missed something please let me know.

Comment: I would disagree there's nothing special about HttpModules and error handling, modules are prone to infinite error sequences for executing on every page.

Comment: @Chris Marisic: A Http Module is just a piece of code.  Whether it errors once an hour or a thousand times a second is immaterial to how you capture and handle those errors.

Answer (score -1):

The question is not really clear because it doesn't express a very specific use case of what you are trying to achieve. In case I partially understood. You are trying to see if there are ways to handle errors of HTTPmodules in a way that would not kill your process at all.

- [ASP.NET Error Handling Using HttpModule, Full and Partial Post Back (Ajax UpdatePanel)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/oshvartz/archive/2008/05/17/asp-net-error-handling-using-httpmodule-full-and-partial-post-back-ajax-updatepanel.aspx)
- [Exception handling using an HttpModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132607/exception-handling-using-an-httpmodule)

Comment: Your second statement would be accurate but then your supporting arguments go directly to my stated issue saying there is no relevant information, that the only information is sidelong related to http modules and exception handling in general but not about exception handling models to follow inside of modules.